# Stuck at reloading related entities for new change from outside?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, desktop-application

The scenario here is for each screen (view) there is one ViewModel behind. And for best (or recommended) practice, we should use one long-alive `DbContext` for each ViewModel.

So there is one requirement to reload the related entities if there is some change (new added / deleted entities) made in another `ViewModel`.

Here are some solutions to this issue:

- Publish some event or send some message to notify about the change, the subscriber `ViewModel`s can:

  - Add/remove the added/deleted entities accordingly without having to reload the entities, this looks like syncing data between ViewModels. It has its own complexity because the added/removed entities here should not have state tracked (meaning the state should be `Unchanged` not `Added` or `Deleted` because these changes have already been updated to database). Also proxied  entities cannot be added to multiple DbContexts, ... too many issues here.
  - Reload all the related entities. This is not naturally supported by EF.
- Just reload the whole ViewModel at the time of switching screen (meaning the ViewModel won't be kept for a whole lifetime of the application). This may be applicable in some cases but actually it's not flexible enough to be used in any case (such as some change may be done from outside the application - another application - usually we just need a Refresh button on the current view to refresh data, so reload the whole ViewModel will affect the current View unnecessarily and may cause some bad visual effect, ...)

So I'm really looking for a good solution to this by reloading the related entities. By Googling around, looks like that this is not easily done by Entity Framework, the quickest and safest way is just create and use a new `DbContext` which means create and use a new ViewModel (please Note that I'm using dependency injection to inject the DbContext into the ViewModel, so the DbContext's lifetime is actually the same with the ViewModel's).

I can Google to find some ***hacky*** code to reload entities in Entity Framework but I don't really like hacky stuff. So if possible please share with me your approach, your solutions to this issue or even persuade me that ***hacky*** stuff is just fine.

Comment: _we should use one long-alive DbContext for each ViewModel_ - I wouldn't say this is true. Another "best" practice stays for creating new DbContext for every time you send sql query. Creating own DbContext for every sql query will give you possibility to load/update data asynchronously, which can be very important for windows applications.

Comment: Agreed. I think you should use a context to *populate* your view model and then discard it. Use a new context for each CRUD action. This can also entail refreshing parts of the view model.

Comment: that practice was read from some site of Microsoft but for Winforms (it says something like each DbContext for a form). But I'm not sure if each form should persist or not (or it did not say anything about that). I've just Googled around and found out that maybe it's best to keep one DbContext for a view but should create a new one (meaning new ViewModel) at the beginning of showing the view. The benefit we take here is ***change tracking***, this is just for desktop application.

Comment: Yeah, you lose change tracking. However, change tracking looks more attractive than it is. For one, the context quickly gets bloated by containing "many" tracked entities and everything gets slow as molasses. Secondly, you're always dealing with stale data. It's probably better to get the fresh "real" entities to populate an edit window and then, for the duration of the edit action, benefit from change tracking, and keep the disconnected view model in sync with the edited entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we should use one long-alive DbContext for each ViewModel

I wouldn't say this is true.
You can and probably should create new DbContext instance for every load/update operation.

Using different DbContext instances give you possibility execute queries asynchronously.
For Windows applications (Winforms, WPF) asynchronous database access has huge improve in loading times, while application remain responsive.
With one DbContext this wouldn't be easy.

Instead injecting DbContext, create DbContext factory and inject it to the viewmodel, then

```
using (var context = _contextFactory.Create<MyDbContext>())
{
    var orders = await context.Orders.ToListAsync();
    return orders.Select(order => order.ToOrderDto());
}
```

But what I am afraid of, is that your business an view logic totally rely on database structure.

Your viewmodel shouldn't depend on DbContext, instead depend on a abstraction of database layer. (actually your question is the first wall you hit when rely on DbContext).

```
public interface OrderDataAccess
{
    Task<Order> GetOrder(Guide id);
    Task<IEnumerable<OrderLine>> GetOrderLines(Guide orderId);
}
```

When you load whole view you can load order and order lines.

```
var orderTask = _dataAccess.GetOrder(id);
var orderLinesTask = _dataAccess.GetOrderLines(id);

await Task.WhenAll(orderTask, orderLinesTask);

this.OrderViewModel = orderTask.Result;
this.OrderLinesViewModels = orderLinesTask.Result;
```

Then when for example you need reload order lines

```
  this.OrderLinesViewModels = await  _dataAccess.GetOrderLines(id);
```

Comment: Yes, I really like to use DbContext as a UoW, open as late and close as soon as possible. But the trade-off here is loosing the benefit of ***change-tracking***. If that feature was not even supported or recommended, I should have tried writing my own helper library to deal with this but it's there and it's confusing the way we choose to go.

Comment: The idea of using contextFactory is very interesting, thanks for that, +1 but please wait for some other answers. This question opens to multiple possible solutions, approaches, not just to seek for the best. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using transient DbContext instances just kicks the can down the road.  Your ViewModel has some entity data that might be out-of-date.  But it also might have unsaved changes.  You simply have to decide how you want to handle that on a ViewModel-by-ViewModel basis.

In a Desktop App the ViewModel *is* the Unit-of-Work, and is still the proper scope for the DbContext.

If you decide you want to reload a tracked entity, or all the tracked entities for a DbContext instance, it shouldn't be a problem.  EG something like:

```
    void ReloadAllTrackedEntities()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            entry.Reload();
        }
    }
```

On a side-note, since you're building a desktop app, did you know [EF Core supports using INotifyPropertyChanged](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2016/11/16/notification-entities-in-ef-core-1-1/) for change tracking?

Comment: _Using transient DbContext instances just kicks the can down the road_ - can you please give an example where transient DbContext can "kick"?

Comment: You still have the problem of identifying the entities that change in other View Models and deciding how to respond, you just are without the services of the EF ChangeTracker, which helps you decide whether to reload the entities or not.

Comment: I highly doubt that this does not work, the `Reload` just load the simple properties, not navigation properties. That's the point. The `Reload` here is one thing considered as official or non-hacky stuff but to actually reload all including navigation properties, the hacky way should be used. And I don't like hacky way which may be unreliable.

Comment: Also I don't want to reload all, just all related (navigation properties) entities of some parent entity, like this `A.Bs`, here all `Bs` should be reloaded. And in fact I've tried something like `dbContext.Entry(A).Reload`, and it did not work. For nav props, we may need to use `dbContext.Entry(A).Collection("Bs").Load` but looks like this also does not work completely for all cases (only fine for the case new entities are inserted from outside).

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, simple leaking `DbContext` and whole database structure to the business or even worth, view layer, will strongly limit possibilities of your application to scale or having more freedom in UI and business logic. Your application become database application.

Comment: @Fabio the _lifetime_ of the DbContext is unrelated to whether or not it or the Entity types are exposed directly to other tiers in the application.  And in this context retaining the DbContext is a clear win on scale and perf, as the alternative is to re-query changed Entities before saving them to detect optimistic concurrency violations.